# Module Build Error: pngquant ENOENT - webpack build succeeds on local OS X, fails on AWS Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack, pngquant

I've tried to find the answer all over, but it just doesn't seem to be out there yet.

I'm using React-Toolbox, React-Bootstrap and some custom scss. On my local machine, the build works fine. When I spin up an AWS Ubuntu server and do a basic node production setup, the build fails on my images.

I'm using Image-Webpack-Loader. I'm chaining this on the file-loader.

Here is my production webpack file (Any tips on this are also super appreciated. Always down to learn)

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const modulesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');

var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

var WebpackEnvPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'),
  PORT: JSON.stringify(process.env.PORT)
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
  './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/assets'
  },
  postcss: [autoprefixer],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.css', '.scss', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel']
      },
      { test: /\.css$/,
        exclude : path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-toolbox/'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader, css-loader!autoprefixer-loader") },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude : path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-toolbox/'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader")
      },
      {
        test    : /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        include : path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-toolbox/'),
        loaders : [
          require.resolve('style-loader'),
          require.resolve('css-loader') + '?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          require.resolve('sass-loader') + '?sourceMap'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
  HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
  WebpackEnvPlugin,
  new ExtractTextPlugin('css/main.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

I've read that by lowering the pngquant quality, that the issue would possibly be resolved, but I've had no such luck.

I get these sort of errors when I build for my different images:

```
ERROR in ./app/images/logo.png
Module build failed: Error: spawn /var/www/project/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 @ ./app/modules/listingpage/listingpage-component.js 55:11-43
```

an error for where I'm including my `main.scss` file in my `index.js`.

```
ERROR in ./app/stylesheets/scss/main.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: spawn /var/www/project/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuildFailed (/var/www/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:315:19)
    at nextLoader (/var/www/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:270:31)
    at /var/www/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:292:15
    at context.callback (/var/www/project/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:148:14)
    at imagemin.buffer.then.catch.err (/var/www/project/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js:42:9)
 @ ./app/index.js 30:0-39
```

And an error I believe having to do with loaders:

```
ERROR in ./app/images/magnifying-glass.png
    Module build failed: Error: spawn /var/www/project/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
     @ ./~/css-loader!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/sass-loader!./app/stylesheets/scss/main.scss 6:6846-6890
```

I'm including my images using the following format:

```
const logo =  require('../../images/logo.png');
```

Lastly, here are my package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.16.3",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "csv": "^1.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.14.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.0",
    "later": "^1.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.3",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.1",
    "react-toolbox": "^1.2.3",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "request": "^2.75.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^15.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.3.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^15.1.1",
    "jest-cli": "^15.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mocha": "^3.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.2",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.1",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "toolbox-loader": "0.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  }
```

I've tried reinstalling my packages, just reinstalling Image-Webpack-Loader, all of the basic things to do. Once again, builds fine locally, doesn't build on server. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, have you found a fix for this? Kinda stuck on it right now

Comment: From what I recall (the project ended up being scrapped), I think all I ended up doing was removing the image-webpack-loader in the image loader chain. I'd suggest trying that.

Answer (score 9):

Just as Rohn John says, I install `pngquant` and `optipng` on my machine and solve the problem

```
sudo apt-get install pngquant optipng
mkdir -p node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/
mkdir -p node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/
ln -s /usr/bin/pngquant node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant
ln -s /usr/bin/optipng node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng
```

and I tested that use `yarn` can do the same and easier:

```
yarn add pngquant
yarn add optipng
yarn add cjpeg
```

Answer (score 9):

Image loader depends on `pngquant` binary.

When `pngquant-bin` npm module is installed it compiles `pngquant` binary using `g++`, `make`, `bash`, `zlib-dev` and `libpng-dev`.

It is unfortunate that the error messages are not clear enough and you're only graced with an unhelpful one.

Make sure to run the following before `npm install` or `yarn install`.

```
apk --no-cache update \ 
&& apk --no-cache add make bash g++ zlib-dev libpng-dev \
&&  rm -fr /var/cache/apk/*
```

You may replace installing `g++ zlib-dev` with `build-base` instead.

Comment: Great answer I had to add this to my alpine-node Dockerfile to get image-webpack-loader loading correctly for my app :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like pngquant installation had encountered on some problems. 
The error message 
**"Module build failed: Error: spawn /var/www/project/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT"** 
means can not find pngquant in node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/.

You can try reinstall pngquant or some other npm packages depend on pngquant.

Moreover you should check if your Ubuntu server has pngquant installed.

Answer (score 2):

Alpine linux has issues with pngquant, check this one out

https://github.com/imagemin/pngquant-bin/issues/65

One solution for this can be linking pngquant by installing it from source ( like https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/community/pngquant/APKBUILD ) before npm/yarn install, but that sounds too much of work to me for just one package.

I faced the same issue, ended up dropping alpine. I am now using standard docker image for node.

Comment: Thanks @avin45h ! 
Was running into a few node issues without realizing it could be node alpine.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue with a rails capistrano deployment where the node_modules was not created properly for pngquant. The command was not found there.

Ended up doing the deployment again with capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem appeared after making some updates to node and npm.
Although everything worked fine after the updating, it crashed by showing the message you mentioned.
After searching a lot I couldn't find another answer so I deleted node_modules folder and installed everything from the beginning.
It worked...